# Visual Studio 2010 locks up when running unit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I'm running MSTest unit tests in VS2010 and whenever I do the VS IDE locks us and goes to '(Not Responding)' if I try to click on it anywhere.

The tests run fine on other people's computers with the same OS (Win7) and the same version of VS2010, has anyone run across this before? Any idea how to debug this?

**Update:** Should mention, I can debug the tests, just not run them without debuging

Comment: Perhaps try running each test individually to isolate if the problem is your local test environment, or a problem with your VS installation.

Comment: We have 1773 unit tests! I don't have time unfortunately

Comment: I have the same problem, sometimes VS just hang with no reason. Kill VS process and restart it then works. One possible reason: the extension installed in your PC may prevent it from running tests.